# Why Valgrind producing "invalid free or delete" if I use "realloc()"?

Tags: c, valgrind, realloc

While using realloc(), I checked it with valgrind as follows

```
 valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes a.out
```

and the error information produced by valgrind is

```
==6402== Memcheck, a memory error detector.
==6402== Copyright (C) 2002-2005, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6402== Using LibVEX rev 1575, a library for dynamic binary translation.
==6402== Copyright (C) 2004-2005, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.
==6402== Using valgrind-3.1.1, a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.
==6402== Copyright (C) 2000-2005, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6402== For more details, rerun with: -v
==6402==
dinesh
vignesh
==6402== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==6402==    at 0x4905E12: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:306)
==6402==    by 0x400539: main (in /user/gur29597/mysourcecode/VMake/a.out)
==6402==  Address 0x7FF000830 is on thread 1's stack
vishwa
==6402==
==6402== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 1)
==6402== malloc/free: in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==6402== malloc/free: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 3 bytes allocated.
==6402== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==6402== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible.
```

My code is as follows ,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *name[2];

 name[0]="dinesh";

 name[1]="vignesh";

  printf("%s\n%s\n",name[0],name[1]);

  realloc(name,3);

  name[2]="vishwa";

  printf("%s\n",name[2]);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the correct answers below, you should be careful to pass a size in bytes to `realloc()`. `realloc(name,3);` will not do what you want even even if `name` properly points to a block allocated with `malloc()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program causes **Undefined Behavior** and valgrind correctly points it out.

Reference:

**C99 Standard 7.20.3.4-1: The realloc function:**

*Synopsis*

> #include 
>   void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);

**Para 3:**

> **If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the speciﬁed size. Otherwise, ifptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`,`malloc`,or `realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the `free` or `realloc` function, the behavior is undeﬁned**. If memory for the newobject cannot be allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

Note that in your case the pointer being passed to `realloc` is not null ans also was not received by calling `calloc`, `malloc` or `realloc` which breaks the requirements mandated by the standard hence the Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You can use realloc ONLY on pointers that have been returned from malloc or realloc. In other words, your program is wrong.

Comment: +1. Also, the reason for that specific error is that realloc is sometimes implemented as a simple free() + malloc().